# Change UI display order of an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-expressions

I have an `ObservableCollection` that is filled with custom elements of type *Video* runtime. These have the properties of *Name*, *Rating* and *Number of Viewers*.
I want to display the *Video* elements in different orders based on whichever of the three criteria the user chooses during Application Runtime. I created the following `Enum` to store the possible choices:

```
public enum OrderBy
{
    [Description("Video Name")]
    Name = 0,

    [Description("Video Rating")]
    Rating = 1,

    [Description("Number of Viewers")]
    ViewerNumber = 2
}
```

These are fed into a `ComboBox` called *OrderCombo* allowing the user to change the order criteria (I'm displaying the `Description` to the user):

```
foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(OrderBy)))
{
    OrderCombo.Items.Add(((OrderBy)item).GetDescription());
}
```

To avoid sorting, I used LINQ to get the order and I came up with the following:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<Video> GetOrder()
    {
        switch (OrderCombo.SelectedIndex)
        {

            case 0:
                return videos.OrderBy(x => x.Name);

            case 1:
                return videos.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rating);

            case 2:
                return videos.OrderByDescending(x => x.NumberOfViewers);

        }
        return videos.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
    }
```

Then, I call this function every time **a new element is added** or **an element is delelted** or **the user changes the order**:

```
VideoUIElment.ItemsSource = GetOrder();
```

So basically I keep re-calculating the enumerable every time, which workswpf but I'm wondering if there is a **more efficient/elegant way of doing this**.
Maybe store the order in one or several `Func<>`s? I tried them, but they can only be of a (compile-time) fixed type as in `Func<Video, string>` for *Name* and I would rather avoid using implementations like `Func<Video, dynamic>`.

Comment: The is a way to sort in the XML but I forget right now.  A default on the switch would look better there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sort your `ObservableCollection` you should be using data-binding and let WPF do the work.

First let's fix the `ComboBox` that you currently populate manually. For the sake of this review I assume you use your code-behind file as a data-source that is bound to the `Window` via:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Next you need to tell the `ComboBox` where to find the items and how to display them:

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding OrderOptions}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
    SelectedValuePath="OrderBy" 
    SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged">
</ComboBox>
```

It receives the values from the code-behind property (you of course would read the descriptions here with your reflection helpers):

```
public IEnumerable<OrderOption> OrderOptions
{
    get
    {
        return
            Enum
                .GetValues(typeof(OrderBy))
                .Cast<OrderBy>()
                .Select(x => new OrderOption { OrderBy = x, Description = x.ToString() });
    }
}
```

I created a helper object for this combo-box that looks like this:

```
public class OrderOption
{
    public OrderBy OrderBy { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now we need a list of videos:

```
private ObservableCollection<Video> _videos = new ObservableCollection<Video>(new[]
{
    new Video { Name = "Rambo", Rating = 3},
    new Video { Name = "Rocky", Rating = 8},
    new Video { Name = "Turbo Interceptor", Rating = 1}
});
```

where the `Video` is implemented as:

```
public class Video
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Rating { get; set; }
}
```

and the code-behind file has this property:

```
public ObservableCollection<Video> Videos => _videos;
```

Now comes the tricky part. You need to add a new resource to the resource-dictionary. This is a `CollectionViewSource` that initially will sort the items by `Name`.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedVideos" Source="{Binding Videos}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name"></scm:SortDescription>
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

In order for this to work you need to add a new namespace:

```
xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
```

Now you can bind a `ListView` to it:

```
<ListView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedVideos}}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Name">
</ListView>
```

You have probably noticed the combo-box has this `Selector_OnSelectionChanged` event handler that in code-behind is implemented like this to get the currently select `OrderBy`, then the switch is used to change the sorting by first clearing the current settings and adding a new one that changes the property of the `Video` object that is used for sorting. In this example I only used the `Name` and the `Rating`. Now each time you change the selection WPF will update the `ListView` and if you add or delete an item it will use the current setting to re-order it.

```
private void Selector_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var colView = Resources["SortedVideos"] as CollectionViewSource;
    switch (((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as OrderOption).OrderBy)
    {
        case OrderBy.Name:
            colView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            colView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            break;
        case OrderBy.Rating:
            colView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            colView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Rating", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: To implement all this stuff in ideal way MVVM should be used. I recommend to place `ICollectionView` in view-model, bind `SelectedItem` of `ComboBox` to the property in view-model and change `SortDescriptions` when this property changed. It is the case where code-behind can be (and should be) avoided. Also it is preferable to use `nameof` operator instead of string literals with property names.

Comment: @Maxim sure ;-) this example should just demonstrate that using WPF components like the `ICollectionView` might be a better approach then sorting the collection manually... and to some point I intentionally didn't do it the _MVVM-way_ so there's something left for  OP to implement :-]

Comment: Looking at tons of questions on Stack Overflow marked with `wpf` tag where people do `DataContext = this` and set `ItemsSource` in code-behind I came to the decision that it is necessary to force them to use MVVM :)

Comment: Thank you! I had something like this in mind. The `CollectionViewSource`, then, is a kind of _intermediate_ layer between the data and the UI responsible for, say, the _presentation_ of the data?

Comment: @rTECH exactly, it can act between the WPF control and the underlying collection to let you present it with different view. You could for example have multiple views of the same collection and each of them in different order. I wasn't actually sure... should I go MVVM or better not yet so it's a mix of partial databinding and partial old event handling but it would make sense to implement it the way Maxim mentioned.

Comment: This is something I wasn't aware of. One last question: how does this approach do from a performance point of view? I mean, as I wrote above, I used LINQ queries to avoid the performance hit of sorting. So are there performance benefits of using `CollectionViewSource`?

Comment: @rTECH unfortuantelly I cannot answer this question, however I guess you can trust WPF sorting unless you really experience performance issues then you should measure it and only then. It's usually a very bad idea to optimize something without proper measurements. For example both of them may perform really poor but not becasue they are slow but because your object's comparer implementation could be super slow... you should always use a profiler first before judging the performance of anything.

Comment: No problem, it's still very good.